# How Install woocommerce plugin in WordPress on godaddy server

Tags: wordpress

I am running WordPress website on godaddy server. I am not able to install woocommerce plugin due to 500 internal server error.

Comment: Does WordPress and its admin area work otherwise? Did you try installing it from within WP's "Add Plugins" page? Via upload? There are lots of things that can cause a 500 error so we need more details.

Answer (score 0):

500 error come for lots of reasons for the main reason is `MEMORY_LIMIT` increase your `MEMORY_LIMIT to 98M`

For that, Open `wp-config.php`, which by default is located in the root WordPress directory.

Find the following line near the end of the file:
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

Just above that line, add the following line:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

Save your changes.

> For Manual Upload you can do with `FTP` just
>   connect with FTP and go to a `wp-include folder -> plugin folder` you
>   can upload your plugin here.